# How can I Print a result on webpage using php getting from MySql database

Tags: php, html

I have a school website, I have uploaded the students examination result to the database but now I want to make a search bar by which can the student search their result by typing their roll number.
please someone give me the code. please

Comment: I think you can refer the [www.php.net](http://www.php.net). DO NOT expect anyone to give U the code directly,It's a bad behavior : )

Comment: oh am sorry, can you please tell me that what should I learn in www.php.net please

Comment: First of all , you should know how does the **Browser/Server works**, then how to **submit HTML form**, how to **fetch forms** with php API ,how to **access database** with php , how to **display the data** you get from database. It's **necessary** for you to build Web applications width php(or other Server-side language)

Comment: well Thank you So Much! I want something exactly like this page

http://biseb.edu.pk/result-search.php?id=16

Please Open this like and search there the roll number 1536. you will get my idea that what I want exactly.

Thank you so much dear PHPJungle

Comment: okay, glad to see your harvest : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wajahat-aftab - you can always find a great tutorial to do this. Here are few of the links

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_S7_wg87GU
2. http://html.net/tutorials/php/
3. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472391

Basically you need to get the data, manipulate it and send it to the HTML page. Once you get the data in HTML you can present it any kind of look-n-feel as per your needs.

**You can not expect exact answers for such questions - so I suggest you to be more specific with QUESTION and make sure that you also share the source code that you tried so far.**

Comment: well I am new here I wish maybe I got q code for my school site. but anyways that you so much for your kind reply .... actually I want exactly like this page http://www.biseb.edu.pk/result-search.php?id=16

Comment: I can suggest you to go through some PHP tutorial over the youtube. Exact answer can not be given for such questions. Best of luck :)